# Вызов метода скрипта, лежащего на другом объекте

Tags: c#, unity3d

Выполняю реализацию панели умений и появилась проблема с использованием умения находящегося в ячейке.
Суть: есть 5 ячеек, в которых мы можем менять местами наши умения. Нужно понимать, какое умение находится в ячейке и при нажатии на бинд(кнопка использования спелла) ячейки, вызывалось умение, которое лежит в ячейке.

Есть база данных на сцене, в которой лежат префабы наших умений. По сути это один измененный префаб, в котором меняется [название], [id], [описание], [cooldown], [и сам компонент скрипта с реализацией умения]. **Проблема** заключается в вызове скрипта с реализацией способности, который висит на объекте базы данных, к которому мы обращаемся. Не могу найти способ вызова функций из этого скрипта. Думаю можно создавать одинаковые названия скриптов и методов и при нажатии на клавишу мы обращаемся к объекту бд по id и через GetComponent().UseSkill() вызвать метод, но мне этот метод не очень нравится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашел я решение для проблемы. На скринах мой пример решения проблемы. Я просто решил переопределить метод `Use()` в дочерних классах, которые отвечают за реализацию своего умения. Сначала добавил поле `bool IsUsable`, чтобы проверять, можно ли использовать умение, но как оказалось методы переопределяются не во всех дочерних классах, а только на том, на котором лежит `override`-метод. Не знаю насколько этот метод может существовать, но если вам нужно что-то рабочее, то вот.

> На префабе вашего умения должен висеть **ТОЛЬКО** скрипт с реализацией умения(в примере Spell1 или Spell2) без скрипта `Skill`, Иначе работать не будет!!!

[image: Обработчик нажатия кнопки(то что в Start не считайте серьезным, это для примера сделал)]

[image: Базовый класс для классов-реализаторов][image: Использование второй способности]

[image: Использование первой способности][image: Результат выполнения работы]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]