# Как правильно наследовать поля в C# Юнити

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, наследование, unity3d-android

Я хочу понять следующее..Допустим у меня есть класс в котором масив и метод:

```
public class PoolManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Pool> poolOfPools = new List<Pool>();
    public Pool GetPool(string poolName)
    {
        Pool pool = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < poolOfPools.Count; i++)
        {
            if (poolName == poolOfPools[i].name)
            {
                pool = poolOfPools[i];
                return pool;
            }
        }
        return pool;
    }
}
```

и есть другой класс,который наследует вышеуказанный:

```
public class PlatformsLoader : PoolManager
{
    public string poolName = "Platforms";
    public Pool platformPool = new Pool();
    private void Start()
    {
        platformPool = GetPool(poolName);
        print(platformPool.pool.Count);
    }
}
```

моя цель проста:вызвав в дочернем классе нужный метод родителя,указав в параметре имя нужного элемента массива,перебрать массив и найти тот самый элемент и затем уже с ним работать.
В скрипте в, родительском классе сам,массив пуст,но я его заполняю через инспектор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по какой то причине при обращении из дочернего класса в метод в **PoolManager**,он использует не массив в этом классе,элементы которого указанны в инспекторе,а экземпляр этого массива,который находится в дочернем классе.(очень некрасиво объяснил,но вот скрины объекта на котором висит дочерний класс):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сами элементы масива являются классами **Pool**:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Pool
{
    public string name;
    public GameObject poolAnchor;
    public PoolType poolType;
    public List<GameObject> pool = new List<GameObject>();
}
```

Я новичок,так что жду помощи....
Спасибо!!!

Comment: `он использует не массив в этом классе, ...а экземпляр этого массива` что?.

Comment: Насколько я понял, ты где-то там заполнил массива на объекте с компанентом  `PoolManager` и ожидаешь, что совершенно другой объект с компанентом `PlatformsLoader` будет обращаться к первому объекту...?

Comment: @Yaroslav       Да,именно так я и думал,так как PlatformsLoader наследует PoolManager...Если же так нельзя,то как я могу обратиться к масиву PoolManager'а,который в свою очередь заполнен в инспекторе?

Comment: Тебя не смутило то, что ты можешь наделать и заполнить 100500 `PoolManager` и ещё заполнить 100500 `PlatformsLoader`...?

Comment: @Yaroslav Ты про то,что бы заполнить 2 массива?Это просто очень неудобно...

Comment: Эти объекты никак не связаны. От слова совсем. Наследуются только поля и методы и у `PlatformsLoader` можно увидеть поле `poolOfPools` унаследованное от `PoolManager `.

Comment: @Yaroslav      А можно их как то связать?Как то получить значения полей,которые находятся у PoolManager ?Или здесь нужно использовать что то другое?

Answer (score 0):

Не могу оставлять комментарий, отвечу так. Когда ты наследуешь дочерним у базового класса поля, то в дочернем они все будут равны null, т.к. поля эти переопределяются и обращаться нужно именно к его полям. У меня была похожая проблема. Я пытался переопределить методы и когда закинул дочерний класс на объект, то заметил там поля базового класса и мало того, обращение шло именно к полям дочернего класса, а не базового, т.к. я его переопределил. Правда оба скрипта лежали у меня на одном объекте, но это не меняет сути.
Вот ссылка [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108712/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5)
Попробуй, может поможет. Там конечно не твоя проблема, но вроде что-то похожее.

Comment: Спасибо,попробую!